# wp_login_url not working correctly

Tags: login, admin-menu, options

I'm working on a project where I need to add a custom link to admin menu, and I'm using the following code for it:

```
$login_url = wp_login_url();
add_options_page('Login', 'Login Page', 'manage_options', 'loop.php?url='.esc_url($login_url).'');
```

Here's a thing. The above code is adding following URL to menu:

http://example.com/wp-admin/loop.php?url=http:/example.com/wp-login.php

Instead of:

http://example.com/wp-admin/loop.php?url=http://example.com/wp-login.php

What's different?

It's generating the URL with only **http:/** instead of **http://**

I even tried it without esc_url but it's still not working.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_options_page( $page_title,  $menu_title,  $capability,      $menu_slug,      $function);
add_options_page( 'Login',      'Login Page', 'manage_options', 'loop.php?url='.esc_url($login_url).'');
```

You're trying to feed a URL to an option that takes only a slug.

> $menu_slug
>   (string) (required) The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu).
>   Default: None

from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page

You can easily add a link to the admin bar at the top of the screen:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_mypage', 999 );

function toolbar_link_to_mypage( $wp_admin_bar ) {
  $args = array(
      'id'    => 'my_page',
      'title' => 'My Page',
      'href'  => 'http://mysite.com/my-page/',
      'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-toolbar-page' )
  );
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

( https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-admin-menu-item-that-links-to-a-url )

I've been going through http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus and it appears that you might not be able to hardcode a link in the admin menu. Every function requires a `slug` to an existing page.

Could you create an options page and have the link there instead?

Comment: Makes sense. I'll go with an option page with a link to the page :) Thanks!